# How does flash filesystem wear leveling work?

Tags: flash, wear-leveling

I am trying to write a little filesystem on flash devices. There are some problems on understanding how the wear-leveling mechanism works. Here is an example of how wear-leveling do:

There is a file, named `file.txt`, and it's content is in some discontinuous blocks (block A, block B and block C). There must be some pointers in every block to point to where the next block is.

So when `file.txt` was changed, such as the content in block B is changed, we need to erase the block B, and write its new content to block B. But if we want to wear-level the blocks, then we maybe choose a new block D to save the new content of block B, but if we do so, the pointer in block A has to be updated to point to the new block D. So,

- Every time block B is wear-leveled, we need to update block A too, am I right?
- How to avoid updating block A every time block B's content is changed? Or maybe there are some mechanisms that do not need to update block A?
- Can any one tell me more details about wear-leveling?

Comment: See: JFFS2 and YAFFS.

Comment: Or dig deeply into UBIFS, if you are considering raw flash memory chips. There's good docs as well as source code available with as much detail as you could care to know. No one here is likely to want to duplicate or organize that info for you. It's already so easy to get, as it is.

Comment: thanks, i just have found the info i wanted in the doc: A Brief Introduction to the Design of UBIFS.pdf http://blog.chinaunix.net/attachment/attach/23/14/19/1423141914f90547264bc8ce75e230aec5f4d1c7db.pdf

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I spent a fair bit of my own time, a few years back, studying these materials and found them very useful. There are a number of different ideas to study in the process and I could not imagine the idea of trying to replicate all that here. I'm glad you found some good materials for your purposes! And thanks for saying so. :)

Comment: See my [survey paper on software techniques for Flash memory](https://www.academia.edu/12769873/A_Survey_of_Software_Techniques_for_Using_Non-Volatile_Memories_for_Storage_and_Main_Memory_Systems) which explains wear-leveling technique and also reviews several wear-leveling techniques proposed in research literature